# To extract a number after apostrophe in a string

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm looking for a way to extract the number after an apostrophe in a string.

Example String = "abc '22 xyz"

What regular expression can we use to extract 22 from the above string? Are there any good sources to understand regex?

Comment: `df['your_col'].str.extract(r"'(\d+)")`

Comment: @mozway that question was already answered here, but not by that topic. This solution presented is to a Pandas DataFrame. Python Regular Expressions (re) would be more appropriate: import re, re.search("'(\d+)", "abc '22 xyz").

Comment: @mozway - thanks it worked. I was having some trouble handing the apostrophe.

Comment: @lucatrex OP used a [tag:pandas] tag, nevertheless I added a pure python dupe